# Flow not clearing out collection?

Tags: visual-workflow

I have a Flow that I created to update a field on the Account object based if a checkbox is checked on another object. In testing, it seems that the collection variable is not clearing??

Here's my flow:

[image]

And the PB workflow to launch the flow has the criteria of:
Primary Contact Checkbox Is changed = TRUE

So the requirement is:
If Contact A has Primary Contact checked, Account field should display Info from Contact A.

If Primary contact checkbox is False and changed to true for Contact B, account field should display info from Contact B.

and Vice-versa. Basically, if the account field should display only the info from the primary contact of the account.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to point the decision node back to the loop node or else it will stay stuck in the decision node.